# iOS: Highlight spelling errors but disable suggestions?

Tags: iphone, ipad

My app implements a custom spell checker with its own window and a different workflow from the built-in spell checker in iOS. Therefore I have switched off correction in the main text input view. This disables the built-in suggestions, but also the highlighting of misspelled words.

Is there a way to keep the highlighting, but disable the suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to roll your own. Here's a rough (iOS 5 and later):

Drop a view with transparent background on top of the text view.

Find the visible range of text like so:

```
- (NSRange)visibleRangeOfTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGRect bounds = textView.bounds;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView characterRangeAtPoint:bounds.origin].start;
    UITextPosition *end = [textView characterRangeAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds))].end;
    return NSMakeRange([textView offsetFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:start],
                   [textView offsetFromPosition:start toPosition:end]);
}
```

Search for misspelled words in that range.

Find their on-screen coordinates using UITextView firstRectForRange method.

Highlight any way you want.

Deciding when to do this is left as an exercise for the eager student :)

Comment: I am getting start and end as nil in ios 7 but its working fine in ios 8.Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to check weather the printed word is correct spelled or not and if wrong then highlight that word

first import

```
#import <UIKit/UITextChecker.h>
```

in your file

```
-(BOOL)isDictionaryWord:(NSString*)word {
    UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [word length]);
    NSRange misspelledRange = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:word range: searchRange
startingAt:0 wrap:NO language: currentLanguage ];
    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound;
    }
```

Comment: Nice code, but unfortunately it does not solve my real problem. As far as I know, there's no way to highlight text in UITextView &c, which is why i want to use the built-in misspelled word highlighter - I just want to disable the built-in spell check suggestions, in favor of my own system.